# angularjs ng-options in not populating my dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I've created a directive that has a isolated scope and for some reason, inside a ng-repeat, i'm not able to access any of my scope values apart from the scope in ng-repeat.  So here, i want to access the isolated scope property authorityList in a ng-options directive but my drop down isn't being populated.

```
(function() {

 var app = angular.module('garageManagement');

app.directive('userManagement', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/directives/userManagementWidget/userManagementTemplate.html',
      scope: {
          users: "=",
          authorityList: "=",
          acceptUser: "&",
          rejectUser: "&",
          selectecAuthroity:"=",
      }
   };
 });

 }());
```

**Template**

```
<div class="form">
<div class="col-12" ng-repeat="user in users ">
    <div id="{{user.Id}}" class="row">
       <label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label">{{user.UserName}}</label>
       <div class="col-3">
     // issue here, authorityList returning undefined
          <select class="form-control"  ng-options="item in authorityList" ng-change="storeSelectionUserType(user.Id)" ng-model="user.StaffType"></select>
       </div>
       <div ng-hide="user.IsApproved" class="col-3">
          <button type="button" ng-click="acceptUser(user.Id)" class="btn btn-primary col-3">Accept</button>
       </div>
       <div ng-hide="user.IsApproved" class="col-3">
            <button type="button" ng-click="rejectUser(user.Id)" class="btn btn-primary col-3">Reject</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Usage**

```
    <user-management users="users" authorityList="authorityList" acceptUser="acceptUser" rejectUser="rejectUser" storeSelectionUserType="storeSelectionUserType" selectecAuthroity="selectecAuthroity"></user-management>
```

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below example.

```
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
 </select>

angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = {
    model: null,
    availableOptions: [
      {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
    ]
   };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to assign key and values in `ng-options`. change it like this

```
<select class="form-control"  ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in authorityList" ng-change="storeSelectionUserType(user.Id)" ng-model="user.StaffType"></select>
```